# How to call yolov7 detect method from a python program

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolov5, yolov7

So far, I am using detect.py with appropiate arguments for the object detection tasks, using a custom trained model.
How can I call the detect method with the parameters(weights, source, conf, and img_size) from a python program, instead of using CLI script?

I am unable to do so.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a `main.py` file where you call all these methods from.

Please make sure you `import` these methods at the top of `main.py`, e.g. `from detect.py import detect` (or whatever you want to call from this file).
Hard to give more precise advice without more input from you.

and then you just run your main file.

Alternatively maybe consider using a jupyter notebook - not the 'nicest' way, but it makes everything more convenient for testing etc.